# Missing parts of Help Menu - Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-luna

I'm working in Eclipse Luna, after install Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE)  Help Menu shows with missing items. I'm attaching a screenshot

[image]

Missing items:

Also, I checked the Menu Visibility:

[image]

- Check for updates
- Install New Software..
- Installation Details
  and So on..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look in 'Window > Customize Perspective'. Select the 'Menu Visibility' tab and open the 'Help' section. You should be able to enable the missing menu items there.

Comment: Thanks greg. I checked the menú visibility and the menues items are enabled. But not shown. :(

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: ok, i've found the solution, first uninstall eclipse (in arch that would be pacman -Rcns eclipse) then head to ~/.eclipse/ you'll see that it kept gtk setting of previous version of eclipse delete all of it, then install eclipse again.

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

this isn't an answer but since my reputation  is < 50, i'll post here

i have similar problem with Gere, i'm running manjaro linux, and eclipse luna 4.4.1.1 and while in Gere case the option is shown in Windows/Menu Visibility in my case it only shows
1. Welcome
2. Help Contents
3. Search
4. Dynamic Help
5. Tips and Tricks ...
6.  About Eclipse

this is exactly the same as shown in Help menu

there are no option for update, nor to install new software

so apparently the problem wasnt in menu visibility as previously in kepler it was ok, the problem only occured after updating to luna, and removing+installing doesnt help

Comment: Firhat, I had to reinstall the eclipse luna. Then I installed many plugins without problems. I never knew what the problem was. I think it is relative to the oracle tools

Comment: i noticed that /usr/share/eclipse/plugins/ is non existant in my case, perhaps it have something to with it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after updating STS based on Luna with OEPE,

It works back after deleting all Oracle related files from the plugins folder.

Then i did proper uninstall from market place.

Install Back OEPE but with only selecting

1. Oracle Java EE tool
2. Oracle Weblogic Server Tools

unchecked every thing else, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem with Eclipse Luna on my Debian.
I did a "`mv ~/.eclipse ~/.eclipse-old`" (for safety :) ),  restart Eclipse and get the "install new software" menu back.

I then remove the `~/.eclipse-old directory`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue Gere. I went to eclipse/plugins folder, search everything with "*oracle*" and deleted them. Once I did that I restarted the Eclipse and voila I got back my eclipse. I hope this helps.