# Eclipse luna showing incomplete help menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I'm using eclipse luna 4.4.1.I installed it recently and it was working fine. I had to uninstall it and again install it. After re-Installing the help menu is incomplete and i'm not able to see install new software option or anything. It was working fine before.

I know this is a duplicate question.But none of the answers there solved my problem.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Since you didn't say which OS you are on, nor which question this is a duplicate of, all I can recommend is you confirm you tried all the things in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285459/missing-parts-of-help-menu-eclipse-luna

Comment: Sorry @jonah.I'm using windows 7, and yes i have tried some of them and some i did not understand